# Existence of a complementary closed subspace extending a given subspace

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional (separable) Hilbert space (or any infinite dimensional Banach space in which every closed subspace has a complementary subspace). Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are closed subspaces of $H$ such that $X\cap Y=\{0\}$. Must there exist a closed subspace $Z$ containing $Y$, which is a complement to $X$ (i.e., $X\cap Z=\{0\}$ and $X+Z=H$)?

This is true in the case that $X+Y$ is closed (such as when $Y$ is finite dimensional): just let $Z'=(X+Y)^\perp$ and $Z=Y+Z'$, orthogonality will guarantee that $Y+Z'$ is closed. My concern is when $X+Y$ is not closed (e.g., it's dense in $H$).

Comment: You answered your own question:  $X+Y$ can be a dense proper  subspace of $H$, in which case no such $Z$ can exist.  BTW: A theorem of Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri says that any Banach space in which every closed subspace is complemented must be isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Comment: Does it follow from the existence of such a $Z$ that $X+Y$ has a complement? I might just be missing something simple.

Comment: Hint: If $X\cap Y =\{0\}$, then $X+Y$ is closed iff their unit spheres are a positive distance apart.  This is a standard exercise in functional analysis books.

Comment: Got it. That is a useful lemma!